# What should I do with my popular question, which attracts a lot of low quality answers

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, moderation

I have asked a question on SO, which happened to [become popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger). The problem is that it started to attract a lot of low quality answers (some of them has nothing to do with the question). Currently it has 27 answers and out of them maybe 4 are useful.

Previously I was flagging every new bad answer for moderators (but most of them came back as - you should not flag wrong answers, downvote them). The thing is that I can not (actually I can, but do not want to downvote each of 20+ bad answers). Is there any other way to get rid of bad answers?

Comment: Downvote all of them. And then crowdsource some delete votes.

Comment: You "do not want to"?

Comment: For the record, it only has 20 extant answers; the count includes deleted ones if you can see them.

Comment: Look for duplicate answers, because those will tend to show up a lot. Moderators will delete duplicates, as long as you can prove that an answer is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: Post in the [JavaScript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript). To be fair though, I haven't taken a close look at the question, but it looks like one of those type of errors that can be caused by a lot of different situations. Maybe the best solution is just to have someone give a more comprehensive answer, and then you can definitely have new, duplicate answers deleted.

Comment: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) "To avoid misunderstanding, I realise that feature like this would make it _technically harder_ for me to post an answer. Imagine I am willing to add 20th answer to some question, that would mean I have to pass through checking 19 prior answers before posting my own, go figure..." :)

Comment: have you tried just not scrolling down?

Comment: @SamIam when answers are shown in _active_ tab (which I find most convenient at sites I frequent, for obvious reasons), crappy late answers flow to the top

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I do not want to. Because in current situation, for one upvote there should be 5 downvotes for the person to lose his reputation. So a lot of them will not remove the answer because who knows may be someone will upvote it and they will still be in +.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You do not want to _what_? I have no idea what you're talking about, sorry. Nobody can upvote deleted posts.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry for being vague. I told that "I do not want to downvote each of 20+ bad answers. Just because I will downvote the answer once, it will not be deleted.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Okay but every little helps! Maybe there were already 4 and you are the 5th... Refusing to vote just because others possibly may not do the same is kinda silly.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this situation myself, also on SO. The very first thing I did was ask myself, "Is this question clear?" After stepping away from it, and looking at it with a bit of objectivity, I realized it might not be. I started posting comments in the answers, responding to comments on my question, and doing edits to clear up the question and make sure it was obvious what I was asking. This not only saved the question, but also helped a solid answer form from that question. The next thing to do, if you're certain that all is well and right with your question, is start doing what you've done already and just flag away the bad answers until something rises to the top. Hopefully the lot of us here will eventually find our way to it and help that natural process occur with our own votes/downvotes. And don't be afraid to downvote yourself (just consider commenting in a helpful manner. This might help you see your question from a different perspective as well).